# how to call a method every min automactic in C# winform

Tags: c#-3.0, c#-2.0

Run a function every 5 sec automatically in C# winform 
when a program execute i call a method into load how can i put this code in c# winform

public void InitTimer()

```
{
    timer1 = new Timer();
    timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    timer1.Interval = 200; // in milliseconds
    timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("test");
}
```

Comment: But isn't your code working? One thing you have to change is the interval to 5000 (5sec). But otherwise, I don't know what exactly is your doubt

Answer (score 0):

Replace 200 to 5000

```
public void InitTimer()
{
    timer1 = new Timer();
    timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    timer1.Interval = 5000; // in milliseconds => 1 sec = 1000 millisec
    timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("test");
}
```

Comment: i know that but my question is where i put this method like load etc....

Comment: I don't know your business but I suggest to used it in `constructor`

Answer (score 0):

if your working with visual studios, in the tool box drag a timer to the form set the interval to 5000, set enabled to true. this will automatically start the timer on load, otherwise in form load use

```
timer1.Start();
```

this will start the timer on page load.